# how to plot specific chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I plot such chart with arrows on label and dashed lines from the values using Matplotlib, is it real?

x_axis = [9, 8, 11, 11, 14, 13, 16, 14, 14] y_axis = [9, 16, 15, 11, 10, 11, 10, 8, 8]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbeie.jpg)

Comment: could you give the list of x and y pair values?

Comment: x_axis = [9, 8, 11, 11, 14, 13, 16, 14, 14]
y_axis = [9, 16, 15, 11, 10, 11, 10, 8, 8]

Answer (score 0):

[`matplotlib.pyplot.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hlines) are used for the dashed lines. Likewise `.vlines`

For the axis check out this tutorial for
[`set_axisline_style("-|>")`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axisartist/demo_axisline_style.html)